# How to search a field containing [ and/or ] in it in SOLR?

Tags: apache, solr

I have SOLR setup.

I want to search all documents having `[` or `]` in it.

I have tried

```
nk_title:"\["
```

But it returns all documents in my DB.

Tried

```
nk_title:[*
```

But it gave

```
  "error": {
    "msg": "org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse 'nk_source:156 AND nk_title:[*': Encountered \"<EOF>\" at line 1, column 29.\nWas expecting one of:\n    \"TO\" ...\n    <RANGE_QUOTED> ...\n    <RANGE_GOOP> ...\n    ",
    "code": 400
  }
```

I also tried

```
nk_title:\[*

nk_title:*[*
```

But returns empty results.

Comment: What is the definition of the `nk_title` field? If the field type is stripping `[` as part of its analysis and tokenizer chain, you won't be able to generate a match at all. Wildcards are (usually) only suitable for fields defined as `string` or a textfield with a `KeywordTokenizer`.

Comment: Definition? Its string type

Comment: And what's the content you're trying to search?

Comment: Searching for the titles containing [ or ] in it

Comment: I understood that - do you have an example of a title you're trying to search (anonymized if necessary)?

Comment: Example, microsoft buys github [page 1]

Comment: Then a string field and your wild card examples should work, `title:*\[*` gives results when testing here - hits both `"title":"[This is a title"` and `"title":"This is [a title",`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search for `[`, just make sure to escape it with `\` when creating the query. Given a collection with a `title` field defined as `string` with three documents:

```
{
    "id":"doc1",
    "title":"This is a title",
    "_version_":1602438086510247936
},
{
    "id":"doc2",
    "title":"[This is a title",
    "_version_":1602438093178142720
},
{
    "id":"doc3",
    "title":"This is [a title",
    "_version_":1602438101227012096
}
```

Querying for `title:[*` gives `doc2` as a hit:

```
 {"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[{
    "id":"doc2",
    "title":"[This is a title",
    "_version_":1602438093178142720}]}
```

And wildcarding on both sides work as you expect (`title:*\[*`):

```
"response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"docs":[
{
    "id":"doc2",
    "title":"[This is a title",
    "_version_":1602438093178142720},
  {
    "id":"doc3",
    "title":"This is [a title",
    "_version_":1602438101227012096}]
}}
```

Comment: That wildcard does not work here ... (I am new to SOLR) 
See I have this post https://imgur.com/a/UzJ6jxC but it returns empty results when I put in wildcard https://imgur.com/a/VVNcU9u

Comment: Are you _REALLY_ sure that your field type is `string`? Because the behavior you're seeing does not match a field defined as `string`. Again: _If the field type is stripping [ as part of its analysis and tokenizer chain"_. A text field with a StandardTokenizer will split the text into tokens on `[` (among other chars), meaning that will not be stored in the field's tokens.

Comment: If you see the first "Field type" definition there, you can see that you have a `TextField` and not a `StrField`. The default tokenizer (if you haven't defined these fields yourself and are using the schemaless mode) is a StandardTokenizer. The Standard Tokenizer will break the original text into tokens, and one of those breakpoints is `[` and `]`. So `Foo [bar` will be stored as `Foo` and `bar` - and the breakpoint will be discarded. When using a wildcard, analysis does not happen, and since there is no token matching `[` - you don't get a hit. Explicitly define the field a `string`.

Comment: Ok, as I said I am new to SOLR, so pardon my lack of knowledge. Can you confirm there is no way to search `[` or `]` keeping the existing schema?

Comment: Not with the field type you have defined, no.